# The ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]=\{a+b\sqrt{2}:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is a UFD. Contradiction?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Considering the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]=\{a+b\sqrt{2}:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, I know that this ring is an euclidian domain and therefore a unique factorization domain.

Now, $23=(3+4\sqrt{2})(3-4\sqrt{2})=(11+7\sqrt{2})(11-7\sqrt{2})$.

$(3+4\sqrt{2}),(3-4\sqrt{2}),(11+7\sqrt{2}),(11-7\sqrt{2})$ are irreducibles in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$, since for example: $$N(3+4\sqrt{2})=(3+4\sqrt{2})(3-4\sqrt{2})=-23$$Where $N$ is the norm $N(a+b\sqrt{d})=(a+b\sqrt{d})(a-b\sqrt{d})$. Since $23$ is prime, $(3+4\sqrt{2})$ is irreducible.

Therefore $23$ is not expressed by a unique product of irreducibles, doesn't this contradicts the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is UFD?

Comment: $\sqrt 2$ or $\sqrt {-2}$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no contradiction because $3+4\sqrt{2}$ and $11+7\sqrt{2}$ are associates:
$$
\frac{11+7\sqrt{2}}{3+4\sqrt{2}} = 1+\sqrt{2}
$$
and $1+\sqrt{2}$ is a unit, since it has norm $-1$. Or note that
$$
\frac{3+4\sqrt{2}}{11+7\sqrt{2}} = -1+\sqrt{2}
$$

Comment: How do you solve $\frac{11+7\sqrt{2}}{3+4\sqrt{2}}$?

Comment: @mathie12, multiply both by $3-4\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: But how did you come up with $3-4\sqrt{2}$? Is there a general method I can use to  divide two elements of $\mathbb{Z}/2$?

Comment: @mathie12, it's like division of complex numbers: you multiply both by the conjugate of the denominator. Here, conjugate means with respect to $\sqrt 2$, not $\sqrt{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

There is just a calculation mistake, since 
$$
(3+4\sqrt{2})(3-4\sqrt{2}) = 9 - 32 = -23
$$